# Select column in latest record in joined table while grouping on original table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let us say we have three Postgres tables:

- book_details that correspond to a given observation of a given book. book_details are never updated, only new observations are added. But only the most recent for a given book is relevant.
- rental_events indicate that a reader borrowed books in a given period
- book_rentals indicate which books were borrowed in that rental. They are unique on (rental_id, book_id).

Or using simplified table definitions:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_details(
        book_id bigint NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR,
        category VARCHAR,
        author_id bigint NOT NULL,
        updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_rentals(
        rental_id bigint NOT NULL,
        book_id bigint NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (rental_id, book_id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rental_events(
        rental_id bigint NOT NULL,
        reader_id bigint NOT NULL,
        started_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        ended_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
    );
```

Now let us say we would like to get the 5 most rented books and their *latest* title (the title in the latest matching book_details entry). What would be an efficient way to do that? (Completing the pseudo query below.)

```sql
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT book_rentals.rental_id) AS rental_count,
               [[latest(book_details).title)]]
        FROM book_rentals
        INNER JOIN book_details
        ON book_rentals.book_id = book_details.book_id
        GROUP BY book_rentals.book_id
        ORDER BY rental_count DESC
        LIMIT 5;
```

And finally the same question, but considering only books that are *currently* considered to be in a given category, that is only books for which `latest(book_details).category = 'Sci-Fi'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CTE` that returns the latest observation of each book and join to `book_rentals` and aggregate:

```
WITH books AS (
  SELECT b.book_id, b.title, b.category
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn
    FROM book_details
  ) b  
  WHERE b.rn = 1
)  
SELECT b.title, COUNT(DISTINCT r.rental_id) AS rental_count
FROM books b INNER JOIN book_rentals r 
ON r.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE b.category = 'Sci-Fi'
GROUP BY b.book_id, b.title
ORDER BY rental_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I'm not sure if `DISTINCT` is needed in `COUNT(DISTINCT r.rental_id)` or you could just use `COUNT(*)`.
Remove the `WHERE` clause so your query searches for all the books.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend phrasing the logic like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (br5.book_id) br5.title, br5.rental_count
FROM (SELECT br.book_id, COUNT(DISTINCT br.rental_id) as rental_count
      FROM book_rentals br
      GROUP BY br.book_id
      ORDER BY rental_count DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) br5 JOIN
     book_details bd 
     ON br5.book_id = bd.book_id
ORDER BY br5.rental_count DESC, br5.book_id, bd.updated_at DESC;
```

The subquery reduces the size number of books to 5.  *Then* it looks for the most recent title in `book_details`.